# merging multiple code blocks together

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm programming in JS. I want to but multiple same "code blocks" into one code block using regex. Please note **second block** is another distinct block.

#### Example Data

```
BEFORE ENTRY
  Im on the top
  block
END

RANDOM NAME
  HAHA I MAKE A PROBLEM 
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  some randon
  strings with also 1 numbers 1
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  more strings
  very cool
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  stringi
  pizza
END
```

#### Desired Output

```
RANDOM NAME
  HAHA I MAKE A PROBLEM 
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  Im on the top
  block

  some randon
  strings with also 1 numbers 1

  more strings
  very cool

  stringi
  pizza
END
```

(i don't care whether RANDOM NAME is on top or on the bottom.)

#### My failed attempts

1. `/(?<=BEFORE ENTRY[^]*?)END[^]*?BEFORE ENTRY/g` replace with `""` (works if BEFORE ENTRY blocks are consequent)
2. `/(BEFORE ENTRY)([^]*?)(END)/g` playing around with `\1 , \2, \3` . Would work if I could somehow merge the capturing groups.

#### Edit regarding @Archer comment: Data-type is a multiline string inside `output:`.

```
arr = [{id:"1", output:">>EXAMPLE DATA<<"},...,{id:"n", output:">>Some similar Data<<"}]
```

Comment: I don't think I'd use regex for this at all. As it looks line-oriented, I'd just break it into lines and scan through, keeping track of the blocks.

Comment: @Archer Its plain text format like above.

Comment: Are the blocks always indented as you show? Do they always end with `END` at the beginning of the line?

Comment: But is it a text file that you're reading, or is it in a string, or an array etc.?  The way you access the data bears heavily on the way you approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: sorry i didn't see the `perl` tag.. sould i remove the answer? the logic is still re-usable..**

If you want to use regex, i would use the second one which is simpler, and capturing groups. In addition, i made the solution generic with an array of keys.

Note that using a function for the `replace`, in addition to be able to control that the result is inserted only for the first match, also disables the special replacements such as `$$` that could be in the result.

You're not obliged to store results in an array, you could use a local var for result.

```js
var codeInput = `BEFORE ENTRY
  Im on the top
  block
END

RANDOM NAME
  HAHA I MAKE A PROBLEM 
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  some randon
  strings with also 1 numbers 1
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  more strings
  very cool
END

BEFORE ENTRY
  stringi
  pizza
END`,
  ending = 'END',
  keys = ['BEFORE ENTRY', 'RANDOM NAME'],
  i, len = keys.length, reg, match, results = {}, inserted;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
  //getting all the contents
  reg = new RegExp(keys[i] + '([^]*?)' + ending, 'g');
  while(match = reg.exec(codeInput)){
    if(!results[keys[i]]){
      results[keys[i]] = keys[i];
    }
    results[keys[i]] += match[1];
  }
  //inserting the result: replace the first one by result, remove others
  if(results[keys[i]]){
    results[keys[i]] += ending + '\n';
    inserted = false;
    codeInput = codeInput.replace(reg , function(){
      if(!inserted){
        inserted = true;
        return results[keys[i]];
      }
      return '';
    });
  }
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = codeInput;
```

```html
<pre id="result"><pre>
```

Comment: No I added the perl tag because perl users have high regex skills. I need a JS solution. Should I better remove the PERL tag?

Answer (score 1):

Using perl

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $f = 0;
my $before_entry;
while(<DATA>)
{
    $f = 1 ,  next if(/^BEFORE ENTRY/);
    print and  $f = 0 ,  if(/^END/ && $f == 2);
    $f = 0 if(/^END/);
    print and next if($f == 2);
    $f = 2  if(/^(?!BEFORE ENTRY|\s+)/ && $f != 1);
    $before_entry.=$_ if ($f == 1);
}

print "BEFORE ENTRY\n$before_entry\nEND\n"

__DATA__
BEFORE ENTRY
Im on the top
block
END

RANDOM NAME
HAHA I MAKE A PROBLEM 
END

BEFORE ENTRY
some randon
strings with also 1 numbers 1
END

BEFORE ENTRY
more strings
very cool
END

BEFORE ENTRY
stringi
pizza
END
```